# INNER JOIN in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database, consisting of 8 tables. I am linking my php code with my database, now what i am trying to do is to join two columns of the two separate tables and display them together in my php page. But whenever I execute my page it does not provide any output. Its totally empty. Kindly help me out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>SlickRed | florida web design</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
session_start();
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed". mysql_error());
    }
$select_db = mysql_select_db('hamdard_attendance');
if(!$select_db){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
    }

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query_one = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$username."' AND user_pass = '".$password."'";
$result = mysql_query($query_one) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}else{
echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
}
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
}


?>
<div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1 style="text-align:left">Quality Management<span class="off"> Cell</span></h1>

        </div>   

        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Attendance</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
                <li class="menuitem"><a href="#">Settings</a></li>

            </ul>
            <a style="text-align:right" href="#">Logout</a>
        </div>





        </div>




        <div id="content">


        <div id="content_top"></div>
        <div id="content_main">
<?php echo "<h2> Welcome ".$username."</h2>"?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['stdnt_name']) && isset($_POST['course_name']) && isset($_POST['stdnt_rfid_tag']) && isset($_POST['student_id']) && isset($_POST['course_id'])){
$username = $_POST['stdnt_name'];
$password = $_POST['course_name'];
$username = $_POST['stdnt_rfid_tag'];
$password = $_POST['student_id'];
$username = $_POST['course_id'];

            $query_two = " SELECT s.stdnt_name, c.course_name FROM students s INNER JOIN student_courses sc ON s.stdnt_rfid_tag = sc.student_id INNER JOIN courses c ON sc.course_id = c.    course_id";
    $result_attendance = mysql_query($query_two) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_attendance)){
        echo $row[1]." ".$row[2]."<br/ >";
        }}
?>

            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

        <div id="content_bottom"></div>

            <div id="footer"><h3><a href="http://www.bryantsmith.com">florida web design</a></h3></div>
      </div> 
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here if(isset($_POST['stdnt_name']) && isset($_POST['course_name']) && isset($_POST['stdnt_rfid_tag']) && isset($_POST['student_id']) && isset($_POST['course_id'])) you are checking if all the fields are having values. So if any one of the fields does not have value then the above statement will not be executed. what are $row[1] and $row[2] ?

Comment: row[1] and row[2] are the two columns which I am trying to join..

Comment: first turn on your error_reporting settings and find out what type error in your code. ini_set('display_errors',1);

Comment: can you guide me up, how to do it ?

Comment: @user3595066 how do you display $row[1] or $row[2]. you can display column value like $row['stdnt_name'], $row['course_name'] etc.

Comment: now when I remove the complete "if statement" I get the following error

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' FROM students s INNER JOIN student_courses sc ON s.stdnt_rfid_tag = sc.student' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You say: «But whenever I execute my page it does not provide any output.»
This is the key phrase!
Even you have problems with wrong SQL this script **must** produce at least DIVs mentioned in the middle.

The first thing you have to do is to understand if any reply comes to a browser.
E.g. using Chrome you press F12 and go to Nenwork tab. Then press F5 and pay attention Status. Is it (OK)200?

If 500 — execute your script using command line to find out php syntax errors.

```
php -af yourscript.php
```

It is also possible to see that script does not respond at all (hang). In this case pay attention to `mysql_connect('localhost','root','');` This line theoretically may hang the script, and it depends on your apache and browser configuration, how long you can wait for timeout.

**PS**

Regardless to the question, you are doing dangerous thing when you concatenate (insert) text receved from user directly into SQL code. Leanr more about variable binding and `mysql_real_escape_string` function. Actually your code is at risk of sql-injection.